# Ошибка импорта библиотеки nuitka

Tags: python, eel, nuitka

Объясню, написал софт, который использует eel в качестве интерфейса, пытался скомпилировать следующими командами:

> nuitka --standalone --onefile --show-progress --show-modules
> --remove-output --enable-plugin=anti-bloat --include-package=eel --output-dir=nuitka-build main.py

> nuitka --standalone --onefile --show-progress --show-modules
> --remove-output --enable-plugin=anti-bloat --include-package=bottle-websocket --output-dir=nuitka-build main.py

> nuitka --standalone --onefile --show-progress --show-modules
> --remove-output --enable-plugin=anti-bloat --include-package=eel,bottle-websocket --output-dir=nuitka-build main.py

и во всех случаях при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~3\main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~3\eel\__init__.py", line 9, in <module eel>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ext' from 'bottle_websocket' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~3\bottle_websocket\__init__.py)
```

может кто сталкивался с похожей ситуацией